# How to catch newline and ignore \n in antlr

Tags: string, antlr

I have problem with string token in antlr. I must accept string like "abc\n" but an error  is thrown when i push a string like

```
"abc  




                       "
```

How do i catch newline and ignore \n ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule

```
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"\r\n] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* '"';
```

will match:

- `"foo bar"`
- `"foo\\bar"`
- `"foo\"bar"`
- `"foo\nbar"`

and reject:

```
"foo
bar"
```

If you want to match the rejected input as well, do this:

```
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"] | '\\' [\\"] )* '"';
```